# Limiting the visible dates in UIDatePicker

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdate, uipickerview

Is there a way to limit the date range in UIDatePicker? I'm aware of the maximumdate and minimumdate properties but I'd like to limit the minimum year visible to 2010. I don't want the user to be able to see any years before 2010. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible with a UIDatePicker, but you could achieve this with your own UIPickerView, making sure to implement the UIPickerViewDelegate method, `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` in order to deal with bad dates, like February 30th, (to mimick the behaviour of UIDatePicker).